# How could I solve the error of psql: Argument list too long?

Tags: bash, xargs, arguments, database

I have a script that contains the following psql command:

```
psql -h $PHOST -p $PPORT -U $PUSER -d $PDATABASE -c "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (${SQL%?}) AS query;"
```

when I passed a simple query that query one or two relations, no problem. 
However, when I passed a long query, I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/psql: Argument list too long
```

I found solutions for "Argument list too long" with mv command I tried it, but nothing changed.

I used  `ulimit -S -s unlimited` before the psql command to increase the MAX_ARG size, but still getting the error.

How could I solve the error of psql: Argument list too long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xargs` trick will not work here because psql requires `-c` to be one big string.

Try an alternative approach by putting all the sql in a file called `statements.sql` and launch the `psql` like this:

```
psql -h "$PHOST" -p "$PPORT" -U "$PUSER" -d "$PDATABASE" -f statements.sql
```

To create `statemements.sql`:

```
printf 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (%s) AS query;\n' "${SQL%?}" >statements.sql
```

This command would not suffer from the "Argument list too long" issue as `printf` is a built-in utility in the `bash` shell.

Comment: Thanks. That's works but -c takes less time to execute than -f.